# C# novice in need

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

Below is the code to our `cs.aspx` recall page.  The idea is that we scan a barcode and it references the code to see of a UPC is on the recall list.  If it is, the "STOP SIGN" is supposed to show, if it is not on the list, the "GREEN Light" is supposed to show.  The problem with the code below is that after the "GREEN LIGHT" icon is called, it requires a manual enter on the keyboard for the next barcode scan to work properly.

Here is what the results are:

1. Scan Barcode  12345
2. Green light icon shows
3. Scan Barcode 54321
4. Green light icon goes away  (this is where I need the Green Light to show again or stay)

I am lost. Here is the code  (we use Chrome or Firefox browser to call the `cs.aspx`)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CS.aspx.cs" Inherits="CS" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head id="Head1">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
     </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txtUPC').focus();

            $("input").keyup(function (event) {

                var strUPC = $(this).val();


                if (strUPC == "000035" ) {
                    $("#stop_dialog").show();
                    var lblStopText = "Recalled Product: UPC:000035  Product: Test Scan";
                    $('#lblStop').val(lblStopText);
                    $("#check_green").hide();
                     setTimeout(function () {
                     $("input").prop('disabled', true);}, 800);

                    return;
                }

                 if (strUPC == "037600245289" ) {
                    $("#stop_dialog").show();
                    var lblStopText = "Recalled Product: UPC:037600245289  Product: Hormel Chili Hot No Beans";
                    $('#lblStop').val(lblStopText);
                    $("#check_green").hide();
                     setTimeout(function () {
                     $("input").prop('disabled', true);}, 800);

                    return;
                }

                if (strUPC == "013409128442" ) {
                    $("#stop_dialog").show();
                    var lblStopText = "Recalled Product: UPC:013409128442  Product: Sweet Baby Ray's Baffolo Wing Sauce";
                    $('#lblStop').val(lblStopText);
                    $("#check_green").hide();
                     setTimeout(function () {
                     $("input").prop('disabled', true);}, 800);

                    return;
                }

                if (strUPC == "041130311222" ) {
                    $("#stop_dialog").show();
                    var lblStopText = "Recalled Product: UPC:041130311222  Product: Shoppers Value Pinto Beans";
                    $('#lblStop').val(lblStopText);
                    $("#check_green").hide();
                     setTimeout(function () {
                     $("input").prop('disabled', true);}, 800);

                    return;
                }

                if (strUPC == "041800501267" ) {
                    $("#stop_dialog").show();
                    var lblStopText = "Recalled Product: UPC:041800501267  Product: Welch's Grape";
                    $('#lblStop').val(lblStopText);
                    $("#check_green").hide();
                     setTimeout(function () {
                     $("input").prop('disabled', true);}, 800);

                    return;
                }

                if (strUPC == "041130311208" ) {
                    $("#stop_dialog").show();
                    var lblStopText = "Recalled Product: UPC:041130311208  Product: Shoppers Value Dark Red Kidney Beans";
                    $('#lblStop').val(lblStopText);
                    $("#check_green").hide();
                     setTimeout(function () {
                     $("input").prop('disabled', true);}, 800);

                    return;
                }
                $("#check_green").toggle();

                   enterUPC(strUPC);

                 $('#txtUPC').focus();

                $('#Reset').click();


            });


            $('#Reset').click(function () {

                setTimeout(function () {

                    document.getElementById('txtUPC').focus();
                }, 800);


                setTimeout(function () {

                    document.getElementById('txtUPC').value = "";
                }, 800);


            });


            function doreset() {
                $('#txtUPC').val("");
                $('#txtUPC').focus();

            }


            function enterUPC(strUPC) {


                $('#lblUPC').val(strUPC);


                var dNow = new Date();
                var localdate = (dNow.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + dNow.getDate() + '/' + dNow.getFullYear() + ' ' + dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes() + ':' + dNow.getSeconds();

                $('#lbltimestamp').val(localdate);

                setTimeout(function () {

                    $('#Go').click();
                }, 200);



            }


            $('#Go').click(function () {
                var code = {};
                code.UPC = $("[id*=lblUPC]").val();
                code.strDate = $("[id*=lbltimestamp]").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "CS.aspx/SaveUPC",
                    data: '{code: ' + JSON.stringify(code) + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",

                });
                return false;
            });




        });

</script>


</head>
<body>

Enter UPC: <input type="text" ID="txtUPC"/>
    <br />  <input type="text" id="lblUPC" runat="server" readonly="readonly" style="border: 0px; background-color: transparent;" size="100" />
    <br />
<input type="text" id="lbltimestamp" runat="server" readonly="readonly" style="border: 0px; background-color: transparent;" size="100" />

 <input type="button" id="Go" value=""/> 
 <input type="button" id="Reset" value="Reset"/> 
  <br />
<div id="check_green" style="display: none">

 <br /> <img src="Green.png" alt="Good" />
  <br /> 
</div>

  <div id="stop_dialog" style="display: none">

  <input type="text" id="lblStop" runat="server" readonly="readonly" style="border: 0px; background-color: transparent;" size="100" />
<br />
  <img src="Stop.png" alt="Stop" />

</div>



    <form id="form1" runat="server">



    <br />
   </form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

(I am not sure what I am doing)

Comment: Either with `else if` or a switch statement.  You are toggling `check_green` everytime

Answer (score 1):

This line is incorrect:

```
$("#check_green").toggle();
```

every time you press a key it is going to get toggled. You need to either set it to show when the textbox has focus (and then hide if a match is found), or do something when it loses focus but not to toggle on every key press.